# Java 11 syntax error calling class properties (Car) from another class (Main)

Tags: java, class

**I need help, I'm learning java in the Linked-in paid for course.
The problem is when I try calling class properties from another class to 'Build a car' I get syntax errors and I need help here is the code if anyone could explain what is going wrong I would really appreciate it thanks in advance !

```
import java.awt.*;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    System.out.println("Peter");

    Car myCar = new Car(inputAverageMPG: 25.5,
            inputLicensePlate "1BC32E",
            Color.BLUE,
            inputTailLightsWorking: true);
}
```

}

**Here is the Car class**

```
public class Car {

// Data Types:
// int -> integer 1, 2, 3
// double -> decimal 34.5, 32.1
// String -> "a1a2" or "Hello World"
// Color -> from awt library
// boolean -> true or false

double averageMilesPerGallon;
String licensePlate;
Color painColor;
boolean areTailLightsWorking;

public Car(int inputAverageMPG,
           String inputLicensePlate,
           Color inputPaintColor,
           boolean inputAreTailLightsWorking) {
    this.averageMilesPerGallon = inputAverageMPG;
    this.licensePlate = inputLicensePlate;
    this.areTailLightsWorking = inputAreTailLightsWorking;
    this.painColor = inputPaintColor;
}
```

}

Here are my error messages (including lines)

Line 9: Cannot resolve symbol (inputAverageMPG)
Line 10 Cannot resolve symbol (inputLicensePlate)
Line 12 Cannot resolve symbol (inputTailLightsWorking)

Comment: Please include the error message that you are getting.

Comment: Ok I will edit now sorry.

Comment: Just remove the argument identifiers. `Car myCar = new Car(25.5, "1BC32E", Color.blue, true);`

Comment: Does Java 11 have named arguments in method calls now?

Comment: C# has argument identifiers, Java doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java syntax works like this:

```
Car myCar = new Car(25.5, "1BC32E", Color.BLUE, true);
```

No need to append variable name while passing values, only constraint here is type of value and parameter index should match.

Comment: I will try this now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this works thanks a bunch the lady who I was following was using java 9.'Something' that's why it wasn't working different versions and all !